# MsSQL displaying the most profitable employee for each year

Tags: sql, sql-server

i studied sql a pretty long time ago and i just got this job so im guessing ill be here allot from now...
anyway im trying to find the employee that his sale's profit was the highest for each year
and i know its not really great but here is what i got:

```
create view V_Company_Share as
select sum(s.actualprice-s.ownershare)as 'companyShare',year(s.saledate) as 'year'
from sale s, SalesMan sm
where s.SalesmanID=sm.SalesManID
group by year(s.saledate)

select distinct v.year,sm.FirstName+' '+sm.LastName as 'name', v.companyShare
from V_Company_Share v, SalesMan sm,sale s
where v.year=year(s.SaleDate) and s.SalesmanID=sm.SalesManID
```

thanks allot for the helpers!

Comment: I don't see a question here... is there a problem you're having or something specific you're looking for?

Comment: just need to use an order by year ASC, companyShare DESC and the top employees should float up to the top of their respective years.

Comment: [Asking good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: im sorry for the unclear question....any way what i am trying to do is to display each year and for each year i need to display one employee with the highest sale's profit. now what i get in the view is each year displays 1 time and highest profit like i need but when i try to add the emplyee's name in the second select i get all of the employees in each and every year

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.....

```
    select Max(companyShare),year,SalesmanID (
    select sum(s.actualprice-s.ownershare)as [companyShare]
    ,year(s.saledate) as [year]
    ,s.SalesmanID as [SalesmanID]
    from sale s, SalesMan sm
    where s.SalesmanID=sm.SalesManID
    group by year(s.saledate)
    )
    group by year
```

Comment: im using microsoft's sql and it does not let the main query's columns recieve a column name from the subquery. i mean that at max(companyshare) it does not take the "companyshare" definition from the sub query "sum(s.actualprice-s.ownershare)"  (its true for all the columns but i can fix em all exept of this one.)

Comment: May i know the what error you got while executing it

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query...

```
select Max(companyShare),year,SalesmanID from
(
    select sum(s.actualprice-s.ownershare)as [companyShare]
    ,year(s.saledate) as [year]
    ,s.SalesmanID as [SalesmanID]
    from sale s, SalesMan sm
    where s.SalesmanID=sm.SalesManID
    group by year(s.saledate)
)A
group by year
```

If is wrog in logic try to post demo data with o/p